# iOS 12 URLSession breaks when HTTP request hits and suddenly app enters in background

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, urlsession

For all iOS Version < 12, it is working fine.
I'm testing(iOS ~> 12.x) in my app using basic URLSession and also tried with Alamofire.

**Test Steps:**

**1.** Hit Any HTTP/API Call.

**2.** Tap on home button immediately.

On coming after sometime it comes

```
2018-12-14 13:43:46.968901+0530 NewReader[15364:4847228] Task <519A3F27-90DA-439F-8711-B07EFA62E823>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <519A3F27-90DA-439F-8711-B07EFA62E823>.<1>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <519A3F27-90DA-439F-8711-B07EFA62E823>.<1>"
), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53} [53]
```

I don't know how other app manages this issue.
Also raised issue [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106838)

Let me know fixes or workaround.

**P.S.:** I already tried with **Dispatch** or **Delay** it's not working.

Comment: Just doing Simple API call to fetch data from server

Comment: if its aborting the connection "after sometime", either your request takes too long or you are making multiple requests. basically after 3 minutes it will suspend it. so you need to work out why your request is still running 3 minutes after background

Comment: @Scriptable: I mean i called API and immediately put app in background for 5, 10 and 20 secs just to check.

Comment: My mistake was that using body for post method but http method was set to get by mistake

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure URLSession with background capability. This has always been the case but previously when going into the background it continued to work for a short time (usually upto 3 minutes). It may have gotten more strict in the latest update, or your request takes longer than the time available.

Firstly you need to able background modes in the capabilities tab.

Here is some sample code to show how to setup the URLSession ready for background

```
private lazy var bgSession: URLSession = {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: Constant.sessionID.rawValue)
    //config.isDiscretionary = true
    config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
    return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
}()
```

Code sample and further information available from the following [article](https://agostini.tech/2018/04/08/background-transfers-using-urlsession/)